# SQL Server: How do I display multiple row values in separate columns when the column has multiple values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2016.  I have tables with multiple extended properties, something like this:

```
Column Name   Value
-----------------------------
1      Export 0
1      Desc   blah blah blah
2      Export 1
2      Desc   blah blah
3      Export 1
3      Desc   Fred
```

I want to display it like this:

```
Column Export Notes
----------------------------
1      0      blah blah blah
2      1      blah blah
3      1      Fred
```

It's possible there can be more or less extended properties. I know how to do it when I know the number of extended properties, but I can't figure out how to make this dynamic. Is the only way to create dynamic SQL? Thanks much!

Comment: This is the EAV antipattern, not extended properties. There's no reason to use such a schema since SQL Server 2005 (I think) when the XML type and sparse columns allowed >30K columns per table. Very, very few applications need to store arbitrary columns anyway, which is why this schema is almost never used. When it *is* used, it leads to sever performance and data quality issues. Querying is extremely hard, indexing becomes ineffectual and the data - well, you have no idea whether the data is valid or not any more

Comment: If you have some arbitrary attributes that don't need to be queried and are only known at runtime, you can store them as XML or JSON in a field and use the XML and JSON functions to unpack them. That;s *far*  better than the EAV schema, as each row remains a single record, and the non-JSON fields can still be queried and indexed

Comment: *Why* did you use such a schema? What problem were you trying to solve? It's almost certain there are better ways to solve it, without causing the problems this causes

Comment: These are Extended Properties - sys.extended_properties.  Each column may contain 1 or more.

Comment: Having used extended properties, the result names look nothing like what you posted. You "simplified" the question so much they're unrecognizable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't require dynamic SQL, just conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT [Column],
       MAX(CASE [Name] WHEN 'Export' THEN Value END) AS Export,
       MAX(CASE [Name] WHEN 'Desc' THEN Value END) AS Notes
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY [Column];
```

If you don't know what the values of `[Name]` will be, you'll have to use a dynamic query. As, however, as been mentioned in the comments under this question what you then have is a design flaw, as you're storing different artributes in a single column:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @SQL = N'SELECT [Column],' + 
               STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                             N'       MAX(CASE [Name] WHEN ' + QUOTENAME([Name],'''') + N' THEN [Value] END) AS ' + QUOTENAME([Name])
                      FROM dbo.YourTable
                      GROUP BY [Name]
                      ORDER BY [Name]
                      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + @CRLF +
               N'FROM dbo.YourTable' + @CRLF +
               N'GROUP BY [Column];';

--PRINT @SQL; --Uncomment to debug
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: While this answers the exact problem, the EAV antipattern means there's no way to know how many "attributes' there are.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many extended properties there will be and they could have different names.  One table could have "Export, Desc", another could have "Name, Location, Type".  That's my dilemma.

Comment: @RichUchytil that's the fatal flaw of the schema you used. Don't use it

Comment: Then you'll need to make it a dynamic statement, @RichUchytil , but therefore, Panagiotis Kanavos is correct; you have a design flaw.

Comment: @larnu Thanks, that's what I was thinking.  Much appreciate the code example!  :)